# How to construct a binary tree from given input

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I have to construct a binary tree from some given input. The input comes in below form :
. The first line represents the number of lines(n) of data coming next.
. The next n lines represents the data in the below form :
  1.The first character is the parent node
  2. The second character is the child node
  3. The third character is the direction.(L represents left child, R represents right child)

A sample input is as follows :

```
9
1 2 R
1 3 L
2 4 R
2 5 L
3 6 R
3 7 L
5 8 R
5 9 L
7 10 R
```

Can someone please guide me as to how to write the code for constructing this binary tree.
I know this is a very simple question but can someone please guide me as how do i go about this.

I constructed a simple Tree class like this:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.data = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

But i am not able to go ahead with the logic.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand how a binary tree works and [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).
The algorithm works like this:

```
1. Traverse tree to find parent (first number)
2. If next char is R insert new Tree(secondNumber), else insert Tree at left
3. Repeat
```

It may be easier to save every added node additionally in a dictionary and do a lookup in the dictionary to instantly find it. This only works if your tree does not contain duplicates.
Classical way is to do a tree traversal. Choose any of the linked algorithms above.

Comment: when do i encounter a line like : 2 4 R , in which 2 is the parent then how do i search in the btree where this node 2 is located.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope this helps.